# Flash Run-Time performance testing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, testing

Lee Brimelow got me thinking about my Flash Application CPU and Memory consumption in his blog. So I'm thinking if there is a good (non task manager) tool for performance testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can measure your FPS if you want ... you can put your FPS to the max your system allows ... and then watch the framerate drop as you run your app ... it's at leas an indicator ... :)

you can use `flash.system::System.totalMemory` to have the memory used ...

also, you should have a look at the [sampler package](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/flash/sampler/package-detail.html) ... it can help you identify some bottle necks in your code etc. ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: I've looked into flash.sampler, and obv you can do few things with it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple performance stats display, check out [Mr. Doob's Stats class](https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats).

For a more in-depth look into your application's performance, there is [FlashPreloadProfiler](http://jpauclair.net/FlashPreloadProfiler/).